# How can the spirits of Zanpakuto manifest in the real world?

Tags: bleach

After the Muramasa incident, Rangiku, Haineko and Orihime go shopping and take pictures.

Considering that normal people cannot see manifested Zanpakuto - as an example, Yuzu Kurosaki was unable to see Zabimaru's snake manifestation - how is it possible for Haineko to do things like that without a gigai?

Comment: I've edited this to what I _think_ you mean. If the names are wrong, let me know.  Never heard of anyone named "Hinako" in the series, but I know of a Hinamori...

Comment: Haineko is zanpakuto spirit of rangiku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a filler. So it wasn't explained anywhere in the manga and as far the main story line is concerned, Zanpakuto's spirits cannot manifest a form other than the sword forms. They can however present their true form to the yeilder and no one else, unless you consider that weird equipment Urahara created for the sole purpose of training which is seen early on in the series.

Answer (score 1):

## This is not canon.

That scene is only part of the anime, not the manga. In the manga, nothing similar happens, and your Zanpakuto's spirit only appears to yourself, not anyone else.

There is also no information about any Zanpakuto having used a Gigai anywhere.